# Distribution of sum of correlated negative binomials

Tags: negative-binomial

Is sum of two negative binomial variables also distributed as  negative binomial if they are non-idependent and correlation is $ < 1$? Or not?

Answer (score 0):

No. For instance if $X$ and $Y$ are independent negative binomials and $Z = X+Y$ (which is negative binomial and has correlation $<1$ with both $X$ and $Y$) then $X+Z=2X + Y$ is not negative binomial. (I'll leave the proof up to you since you changed the question on me.)

Comment: Great point! Thank you.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: That's not usually how this works, but ok, will update

Comment: Updated. $X+Z$ is also a counterexample but lacks the snappy one line proof.

Comment: Didn't see you wanted it to be a sum of two, so changed again. At a certain point you have to ask yourself what you're going for. Can you come up with an example of two correlated negative binomial RVs that do sum to a negative binomial? (For that matter, can you come up with a way to construct correlated negative binomials that doesn't feel like 'cheating' to you?)

Comment: Thank you very much,  spaceisdarkgreen. Very elegant approach. Never thought about the support

Comment: @den2042 don't think that works with the new one since the support is still all the integers ... still it would be highly weird if that thing turned out to be a negative binomial. Sorry to be grumpy/lazy and not give a proof. I suggest that there is a relationship between moments that always holds for a neg bin that will fail for $2X+Y.$